# How to install latex with Anki 2.1 on z Mac?

Tags: mac, anki

I've been working on this off an on for over a week.
I need to make some cards with physics equations for engineering purposes.
I think i've looked at every relevant page google can find.
I consider myself an advanced programmer and i'm at home with the terminal.
Still no luck.

Here's the error anki is giving me:

```
Error executing /usr/local/texlive/2019basic/bin/x86_64-darwin/latex.
Generated file: /var/folders/w3/p67pv19524313b_29rrnn2p40000gn/T/anki_temp/tmp.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

! LaTeX Error: File `utf8x.def' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: def)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.165 \endinput
               ^^M
No pages of output.
Transcript written on tmp.log.
```

Also updating the tlmgr is giving me some sketchy output.

```
[DarkKnight@MacBook-Pro Cellar]$ sudo tlmgr update --self
Password:
tlmgr: package repository http://muug.ca/mirror/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2019basic/tlpkg/backups
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] update: texlive.infra [214k] (51561 -> 52975) ... done
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
tlmgr: package log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
[DarkKnight@MacBook-Pro Cellar]$ sudo tlmgr install dvipng
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.forsale.plus/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
[1/2, ??:??/??:??] install: dvipng.x86_64-darwin [482k]
[2/2, 00:01/00:01] install: dvipng [1k]
tlmgr: package log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
[DarkKnight@MacBook-Pro Cellar]$
```

Comment: I don't have a Mac ... but recently installed on a Windows OS and realized that the way it finally worked was to make a minimal installation as a beginning and then add the packages needed ... If you don't find a better way ... Try it after removing the installed version. (oh ... seems you already trying something like this ... Sorry if so...)

Comment: Install the full MacTeX rather than the small but limited BasicTeX. You might get by using utf8 rather than utf8x.